# Getting Utilities.jsonParse is deprecated when I run this Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to run this script  by Ipeenk.com that post to Facebook Groups using Google App Script. But it keeps giving me warn that "Method Utilities.jsonParse is deprecated.Collapse
File: Code Line: 25
The method has been marked as deprecated which means that the feature should be avoided and may be removed in the future. Consider using an alternative solution."

Pls how do I fix it.

```
   //------------------------------ Ipeenk  ----------------------------------//

var robot={
  tokens:[
    {nama:"Ipeenk",token:"CAAAACZ****************"}
  ],
  pids:[
    "653096888*****",
   ],
  msgs:[
    "Hey guys........Hurry up!",

  ],
  pid:""
};

var putaran=0;

function NumpakBecak(almt,prop){
  var a=UrlFetchApp.fetch(almt,{
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
    method:"post",
    payload:prop
  });
  var b=Utilities.jsonParse(a.getContentText());
  return b;
}
function koplo(naon){
  var a=naon.sort(function(){return 0.5-Math.random()});
  a.reverse();
  a=a.sort(function(){return 0.5-Math.random()});
  return a;
}

function ViaVallen(){
  var a=NumpakBecak("https://graph.facebook.com/"+robot.gid+"/feed",{
    method:"post",
    message:robot.msg,
    access_token:robot.token
  });

}
function ipeenk(){
  robot.token=koplo(robot.tokens)[0].token;
  robot.pid=koplo(robot.pids)[putaran];
  robot.gid=robot.pid.split("_")[0];
  robot.limit=50;
  robot.msg=koplo(robot.msgs)[0];
  var a=NumpakBecak("https://graph.facebook.com/"+robot.gid+"/feed",{
    method:"get",
    limit:50,
    fields:"id",
    access_token:robot.token
  });
  var b="n";
  if(a&&a.data&&a.data.length!=0){
    for(x in a.data){if(a.data[x].id==robot.pid){b="y";break}}
  }
  if(b=="n"){
    ViaVallen();
  }else if(b=="y"){
    putaran++;
    if(putaran>=0&&putaran<robot.pids.length){
      ipeenk();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been replaced by `JSON.parse(text)`, see [release note november 2013](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2013)

simply replace in your code

```
Utilities.jsonParse(a.getContentText());
```

with

```
JSON.parse(a.getContentText());
```

> November 18, 2013
>
> The Apps Script methods Utilities.jsonParse() and
>   Utilities.jsonStringify() have been deprecated in favor of the
>   now-standard JavaScript methods JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify(),
>   which now appear in autocomplete.

Comment: Please can you help me take a look at the code. It is not posting on Facebook. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a Google Apps Script issue, rather a possible issue with facebook API. try on another tag.

Comment: Thank You So Much @Serge insas the problem was coming from the .ml domain am trying to post. I think Facebook had marked .ml domain as spam.